# How many socket connections can a web server handle?

Tags: http, tcp, network-programming, hosting, tcplistener

Say if I was to get shared, virtual or dedicated hosting, I read somewhere a server/machine can only handle 64,000 TCP connections at one time, is this true? How many could any type of hosting handle regardless of bandwidth? I'm assuming HTTP works over TCP.

Would this mean only 64,000 users could connect to the website, and if I wanted to serve more I'd have to move to a web farm?

Comment: Apologies to responders, I've ripped through this thread like a tornado. There were simply too many incorrect answers for my liking, and still no direct answer. I use stackoverflow a lot and find many high quality answers. I hope that others will be able to find this thread and find a useful informed answer.

Comment: Hi David, did you find the right answer to this question?

Comment: 64000 TCP connections over single IP of server. You can upgrade your server network to scale and support more than 64000.

Comment: I guess this has the answer to what you are looking for., https://serverfault.com/questions/533611/how-do-high-traffic-sites-service-more-than-65535-tcp-connections

Answer (score 162):

In short:
You should be able to achieve in the **order of millions** of simultaneous active TCP connections and by extension HTTP request(s). This tells you the maximum performance you can expect with the right platform with the right configuration.

Today, I was worried whether IIS with ASP.NET would support in the order of 100 concurrent connections (look at my update, expect ~10k responses per second on older ASP.Net Mono versions). When I saw this question/answers, I couldn't resist answering myself, many answers to the question here are completely incorrect.

**Best Case**

The answer to this question must only concern itself with the simplest server configuration to decouple from the countless variables and configurations possible downstream.

So consider the following scenario for my answer:

1. No traffic on the TCP sessions, except for keep-alive packets (otherwise you would obviously need a corresponding amount of network bandwidth and other computer resources)
2. Software designed to use asynchronous sockets and programming, rather than a hardware thread per request from a pool. (ie. IIS, Node.js, Nginx... webserver [but not Apache] with async designed application software)
3. Good performance/dollar CPU / Ram. Today, arbitrarily, let's say i7 (4 core) with 8GB of RAM.
4. A good firewall/router to match.
5. No virtual limit/governor - ie. Linux somaxconn, IIS web.config...
6. No dependency on other slower hardware - no reading from harddisk, because it would be the lowest common denominator and bottleneck, not network IO.

**Detailed Answer**

Synchronous thread-bound designs tend to be the worst performing relative to Asynchronous IO implementations.

WhatsApp can handle a million WITH traffic on a single Unix flavoured OS machine - [https://blog.whatsapp.com/index.php/2012/01/1-million-is-so-2011/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120108184257/https://blog.whatsapp.com/index.php/2012/01/1-million-is-so-2011/).

And finally, this one, http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html, goes into a lot of detail, exploring how even 10 million could be achieved. Servers often have hardware TCP offload engines, ASICs designed for this specific role more efficiently than a general purpose CPU.

**Good software design choices**

Asynchronous IO design will differ across Operating Systems and Programming platforms. Node.js was designed with *asynchronous* in mind. You should use Promises at least, and when ECMAScript 7 comes along, `async`/`await`. C#/.Net already has full asynchronous support like node.js. Whatever the OS and platform, asynchronous should be expected to perform very well. And whatever language you choose, look for the keyword "asynchronous", most modern languages will have some support, even if it's an add-on of some sort.

**To WebFarm?**

Whatever the limit is for your particular situation, yes a web-farm is one good solution to scaling. There are many architectures for achieving this. One is using a load balancer (hosting providers can offer these, but even these have a limit, along with bandwidth ceiling), but I don't favour this option. For Single Page Applications with long-running connections, I prefer to instead have an open list of servers which the client application will choose from randomly at startup and reuse over the lifetime of the application. This removes the single point of failure (load balancer) and enables scaling through multiple data centres and therefore much more bandwidth.

**Busting a myth - 64K ports**

To address the question component regarding "64,000", this is a misconception. A server can connect to many more than 65535 clients. See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48283/is-a-tcp-server-limited-to-65535-clients/48284

By the way, Http.sys on Windows permits multiple applications to share the same server port under the HTTP URL schema. They each register a separate domain binding, but there is ultimately a single server application proxying the requests to the correct applications.

**Update 2019-05-30**

Here is an up to date comparison of the fastest HTTP libraries - https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r16&hw=ph&test=plaintext

- Test date: 2018-06-06
- Hardware used: Dell R440 Xeon Gold + 10 GbE
- The leader has ~7M plaintext reponses per second (responses not connections)
- The second one Fasthttp for golang advertises 1.5M concurrent connections - see https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp
- The leading languages are Rust, Go, C++, Java, C, and even C# ranks at 11 (6.9M per second). Scala and Clojure rank further down. Python ranks at 29th at 2.7M per second.
- At the bottom of the list, I note laravel and cakephp, rails, aspnet-mono-ngx, symfony, zend. All below 10k per second. Note, most of these frameworks are build for dynamic pages and quite old, there may be newer variants that feature higher up in the list.
- Remember this is HTTP plaintext, not for the Websocket specialty: many people coming here will likely be interested in concurrent connections for websocket.

Comment: Thanks for including links to people talking about how they are doing it.

Comment: What if the single server the client connected to goes down? And what if all your SPA's randomly connected to one server and overloaded it? The idea for using loadbalancers is not just using 1 you can use many as you like

Comment: The clients would randomly select a server. The chances of all randomly connecting to one is practically impossible. Although one could follow up with client count and the server could ask a client to move to another server if too overcrowded.

Comment: Re: the 64K limitation - what you say is true, but it is fairly common for a server app to proxy requests through to some backend service(s), in which case the "server" now becomes a "client" and may well have to worry about ephemeral port exhaustion (eg: https://www.nginx.com/blog/overcoming-ephemeral-port-exhaustion-nginx-plus/). I'm sure you know that, but mentioning it for others (:

Comment: @jwd good point, contextual for nginx on a web app, but for a basic web site, such proxying wouldn't need to occur. The same could also be said of connecting through to a database via TCP by a web application. In theory, this is solved by using all addresses in 127.*.*.* range, but in practice I don't know if this is an available option.

Comment: @Todd I am kind of looking around for Server Sent Event implementation using Nginx and ExpressJS. Just that I wanted to know like how many simultaneous SSE connections will my Ubuntu server handle with its single core CPU and 2GB RAM? I will be needing to send Push Notifications for real-time updates. How well can it scale?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning. There is no prohibitive protocol limit, it's going to come down to the specifics of our system and software (versions) and code. You can try and find some example benchmarks to give you a ball park idea (I just tried - I couldn't find any myself)

Answer (score 63):

This question is a fairly difficult one.  There is no real software limitation on the number of active connections a machine can have, though some OS's are more limited than others.  The problem becomes one of resources.  For example, let's say a single machine wants to support 64,000 simultaneous connections.  If the server uses 1MB of RAM per connection, it would need 64GB of RAM.  If each client needs to read a file, the disk or storage array access load becomes much larger than those devices can handle.  If a server needs to fork one process per connection then the OS will spend the majority of its time context switching or starving processes for CPU time.

The [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) page has a very good discussion of this issue.

Comment: A bit of a mixed answer. The OP appears to be referring to a best case scenario, and including how would be beneficial, rather than finding a worst case and then referring to an article which may have the solution. Noting disk bottleneck is useful. Using Asynchronous IO a very high amount of concurrent clients can be reached.

Comment: How could you say that there's no real software limitation since the port size is itself 16 bit which makes the max no ports available at any instant at max 65.5K. I believe your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Your machine can have more than 1 IP so more than 2^16 ports are available.

Answer (score 12):

To add my two cents to the conversation a process can have simultaneously open a number of sockets connected equal to this number (in Linux type sytems) /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn

cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn

This number can be modified on the fly (only by root user of course)

echo 1024 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn

But entirely depends on the server process, the hardware of the machine and the network, the real number of sockets that can be connected before crashing the system

Comment: While possibly true of Linux, this refers to a virtual limit, not a benchmark of possibilities. This answer is a little specific for my liking, and doesn't provide any number or indication of number of concurrent connections. Despite your efforts, it's not very useful. Maybe you could self-answer a question: "Why can't I server more than X concurrent TCP connections on Linux"

Comment: As far as I can tell this is *wrong*. somaxconn is the maximum number of queued connections on a open socket (i.e. it is the maximum value of the backlog parameter of `listen(int socket, int backlog)`. It isn't related to the number of sockets that a process can have open.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the answer is at least 12 million if you have a beefy server, your server software is optimized for it, you have enough clients. If you test from one client to one server, the number of port numbers on the client will be one of the obvious resource limits (Each TCP connection is defined by the unique combination of IP and port number at the source and destination).

(You need to run multiple clients as otherwise you hit the 64K limit on port numbers first)

When it comes down to it, this is a classic example of the witticism that "the difference between theory and practise is much larger in practise than in theory" - in practise achieving the higher numbers seems to be a cycle of a. propose specific configuration/architecture/code changes, b. test it till you hit a limit, c. Have I finished? If not then d. work out what was the limiting factor, e. go back to step a (rinse and repeat).

Here is an example with 2 million TCP connections onto a beefy box (128GB RAM and 40 cores) running Phoenix http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/the-road-to-2-million-websocket-connections - they ended up needing 50 or so reasonably significant servers just to provide the client load (their initial smaller clients maxed out to early, eg "maxed our 4core/15gb box @ 450k clients").

Here is another reference for go this time at 10 million: http://goroutines.com/10m.

This appears to be java based and 12 million connections: https://mrotaru.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/12-million-concurrent-connections-with-migratorydata-websocket-server/

Comment: Great new links, with a correct understanding of the question. I like the general advice for hit-barrier -> fix barrier. Everyone has a different specific situation, but at least they have an indication here of what is economically/practically achievable. One shouldn't promise a customer 100 million per server any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

in case of the IPv4 protocol, the server with one IP address that listens on one port only can handle 2^32 IP addresses x 2^16 ports so 2^48 unique sockets. If you speak about a server as a physical machine, and you are able to utilize all 2^16 ports, then there could be maximum of 2^48 x 2^16 = 2^64 unique TCP/IP sockets for one IP address. Please note that some ports are reserved for the OS, so this number will be lower. To sum up:

1 IP and 1 port --> 2^48 sockets

1 IP and all ports --> 2^64 sockets

all unique IPv4 sockets in the universe --> 2^96 sockets

Answer (score 1):

There are two different discussions here: One is how many people can connect to your server. This one has been answered adequately by others, so I won't go into that.

Other is how many ports yours server can listen on? I believe this is where the 64K number came from. Actually, TCP protocol uses a 16-bit identifier for a port, which translates to 65536 (a bit more than 64K). This means that you can have that many different "listeners" on the server per IP Address.

Comment: for your benefit I have added an extra section to my answer addressing your misconception. Also this question pertains to "socket connections" not "people", which is an important distinction in the context of this question.

Comment: If we are talking about one single server machine and one single router, I think this answer is right. But @Todd is taking about a farm of server machines, which the user can connect to any of them randomly through a load balancer.

Comment: @amr that's incorrect. My answer is about a single machine. The "Webfarm?" section is there for contrast and advice for going beyond and concludes that load balancers aren't necessary with good architecture. You simply haven't read my answer thoroughly yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the number of concurrent socket connections one web server can handle largely depends on the amount of resources each connection consumes and the amount of total resource available on the server barring any other web server resource limiting configuration.

To illustrate, if every socket connection consumed 1MB of server resource and the server has 16GB of RAM available (theoretically) this would mean it would only be able to handle (16GB / 1MB) concurrent connections. I think it's as simple as that... REALLY!

So regardless of how the web server handles connections, every connection will ultimately consume some resource.