# socket.io: how to handle 4000 users?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io

Has someone one already eperienced like 4000 concurrent users on socket.io ?

- Is that possible on a single (powerful) server or should I use some distriubuted servers ?
- what if use Amazon EC2 : is that automatically dispatched ?

Any experience or good practise is welcome.

Comment: You may want to read this: [512000 concurrent websockets with Groovy++ and Gretty](http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/512000-concurrent-websockets) and this [How many socket connections can a typical server handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575453/how-many-socket-connections-can-a-typical-server-handle)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this url http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/ inspires you to get answers on your questions.
It is **not** socket.io specific but describes a good setup and has some socket.io relevancy in the comments