# What is the limitation of the Azure Web App Socket Number?

Tags: sockets, azure, azure-webjobs

The documents in Azure says the limitation of socket number is unlimited if your pricing tier is higher than standard.
Is it really possible "unlimited"?? If not, how much socket can Azure load simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlimited means that Azure App Service will not enforce any kind of limit on the number of concurrent connections. In practice, you're likely to hit resource constraints which limit the number of connections, in the same sense that your app would eventually reach a limit serving a large number HTTP requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my websites need to create socket with the clients(my websites it's about online gambling) and maybe it needs more than 100,000 socket(or more) in the same time. So is this possible for one instance count?? or i need to create more(it's important for me cause the more instance count will cost money)??
Thanks!

Comment: 100k concurrent connections is rather large and you might need more than one instance, however the only way to tell would be to test it with the actual stack that you are using. Bear in mind that many stacks may limit the number of concurrent connections by default, so you'd have to remove those limits. For more context see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575453/how-many-socket-connections-can-a-typical-server-handle